# SubSonic 3.0.0.2/3 | Structs.tt problem

Tags: subsonic

```
Error   3   Running transformation: System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating29C706144B7FE04D6F958B994FF0596C.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetReader(String sql)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating29C706144B7FE04D6F958B994FF0596C.GeneratedTextTransformation.LoadTables()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating29C706144B7FE04D6F958B994FF0596C.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() C:\Documents and Settings\nobody\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\web2008\SubSonic3ActiveRecords\Structs.tt 1   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting a stack trace?

Structs.tt can't find a connection string in your app/web.config.

Comment: seems the connection string should be at first order. now working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after adding a service reference to a class library project which created an app.config. I guess app.config must take precedence over the web.config. 
I excluded the app.config from my project and solved it for me.